# How to jump to a page in `DocView` mode when a pdf contains a roman numeral numbered introduction?

Tags: pdf, docview

Lets say that I am viewing a pdf in emacs which contains a section numbered with roman numerals. How would I jump to page `xxii` in that section without doing mental math about what that page's number is according to emacs?

Similarly, page `71` in that document might be considered page number `105` by emacs due to the fact that page `1` of the document is actually the 35th page of the pdf, since the first 35 pages were a roman numeral numbered introduction.

I am fine with using a mode other than DocView as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) you can type <kbd>M-g l</kbd> (`pdf-view-goto-label`), which asks for a page-label, which is usually equal to the displayed page-number.